# How to sort or filter the JSON API in java

Tags: android

I have to make a news app and i have done taking internet permission and volley library but couldn't call the news API

JSON API

```
public class newsdemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{

            URL u= new URL ("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=**redacted**");
            HttpURLConnection hr=(HttpURLConnection)u.openConnection();

                if (hr.getResponseCode()==200){
                InputStream im=hr.getInputStream() ;
                String Buffer Sb=new String Buffer() ;
                Buffered-reader BR=new Buffered-reader(new InputStreamReader(im) ) ;
                FileOutputStream fo=new FileOutputStream("d://dede.html");
                Buffered-writer bw=new Buffered-writer(new OutputStreamWriter(fo));
                String line=br.readLine() ;
                while (line!=null ) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                    bw.write(line);
                    bw.newLine();
                    line=br.readLine() ;
                   }}}catch (Exception  e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Android doesn't use main methods - it uses activities. This doesn't use Volley either, and honestly, this doesn't appear to be Android. Create a [mre] and tag properly if this isn't Android.

Comment: Yes, As Zoe, told you are not using volley itself.

Comment: `retrofit2` with `GsonConverter` could map the `JSON` to `POJO`, in order to obtain a sort-able `ArrayList` (just use these search-terms on here to find examples for that).

Comment: this the java file ...tbh i am an intern in a company and they asked me to open the news api and sort out the data from the bundle of the data ...i m having problem in sorting the data ...i have called the data through the JSON api

Answer (score 0):

Android has all the tools you need to parse json built-in. Example follows, no need for GSON or anything like that.

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=**redacted**");
    // Depends on your web service
    httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = null;
    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        // Oops
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
```

@Note: I suggest you to use volley/Retrofit